# How to fix grayed out options on right click menu Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, permissions, menu

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and updated to the latest software. I have replaced hard drive of my laptop with an SSD. Original hard drive is fixed where the DVD drive used to be. Windows and Ubuntu both installed on the SSD. BIT folder resides on my original hard drive. BIT folder is just a randomly selected one. None on the hard drive partitions or SSD partitions allow me to use Cut, Move to or rename options. But the places on the side bar on the picture allow me to do so.

[image]

except the places in the picture below,

[image]

How to fix this problem.

Permission is set like this.

[image]

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=c8b94b00-5f20-45ce-95a2-450940d31e71 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=1a1cf76f-ffee-4437-b9df-e666e600ac87 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions to that location?  The options you mention (cut, move, rename) require that you have write permissions to that directory/location.

Comment: @guiverc I don't know actually

Comment: If you right click & select Properties, then look in the Permissions tab you should see if you can 'create and delete' ..

Comment: @guiverc yes I can see "create and delete"

Comment: @user68186 I replaced hard drive of my laptop with an SSD. Original hard drive is fixed where the DVD drive used to be. Windows and Ubuntu both installed on the SSD. BIT folder resides on my original hard drive. BIT folder is just a randomly selected one. None on the hard drive partitions or SSD partitions allow me to use Cut, Moveto or rename optiins. But the places on the side bar on the picture allow me to do so

Comment: Thanks! You may want to put all this information in the question. This may help others understand the problem better. Also copy and paste the contents of `/etc/fstab` in the question. This will show us how the various partitions are mounted. If you cloned the partitions from HDD to SSD, the cloned partitions may have the same UUID as the original. In that case, either of them should be changed.

Comment: For us to help you further:  Please [edit] your question and provide the information @user68186 has requested and if it's still possible, boot from the old HDD and perform this command: `sort -g -t : -k 3 /etc/passwd` then boot from the SSD and perform the same command and provide all this information.

Comment: @NuwanThisara Were you able to fix this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Changer I actually do not remember if I was able to fix it. After reading these comments as a stranger I think this did not help me to fix it, I usually upvote and accept answers if I could use them. later I installed Ubuntu newer versions now I am on latest LTS but I am not using Ubuntu as my daily OS as of now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its the write Permission on the Files itself within the Folder, to cut them u need write, for copy read is enough.
So you have to go into the Folder u want to move/cut (and all Subfolders) and give yourself write Permission on all contained Files.

```
sudo chmod u+w -r "Path/to/what/to/cut"
```

This might pose a Security Risk afterwards so you can record the Original Permissions with

```
sudo getfacl -aRP "AccessRightsOriginal.txt"
```

and restore them afterwards with

```
sudo setfacl -MRP "AccessRightsOriginal.txt"
```

Comment: As I do not know how to do it please explain how?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/940528)

Comment: @Fabby can you help me to solve this?